# How to send timezone to dialogflow request using php script?

Tags: timezone, dialogflow-es, webhooks, google-apis-explorer, php-7.1

We have a chat interface which we are using to request to dialogflow. Here the chat window is designed in php. 
Now the chat can be initiated in any location, so when user connects we are also trying to capture timezone and send in the request to dialogflow. Based on the timeZone the results also differ.
Now i used the below code to append timezone, based on api considered from github in php.
GIT HUB link from where i have taken the code
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/dialogflow/src/detect_intent_texts.php

The script taken from git hub is as follows

```
// Actual Script
// START dialogflow_detect_intent_text

//namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Dialogflow;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\SessionsClient;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\TextInput;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\QueryInput;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\QueryParameters;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\SessionEntityTypesClient;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\EntityTypesClient;
use Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\ContextsClient;

function detect_intent_texts($projectId, $texts, $sessionId, $languageCode = 'en-US')
{
    $test = array('credentials' => 'apikey/test-cd4f0-XXXXX.json');
    // new session
    $sessionsClient = new SessionsClient($test);
    $session = $sessionsClient->sessionName($projectId, $sessionId ?: uniqid());
    printf('Session path: %s' . PHP_EOL, $session);
    // query for each string in array

    // create text input
    $textInput = new TextInput();
    $textInput->setText($text);
    $textInput->setLanguageCode($languageCode);

    // create query input
    $queryInput = new QueryInput();
    $queryInput->setText($textInput);

    // get response and relevant info
    $response = $sessionsClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput);
    $queryResult = $response->getQueryResult();
    $queryText = $queryResult->getQueryText();
    $intent = $queryResult->getIntent();
    $displayName = $intent->getDisplayName();
    $confidence = $queryResult->getIntentDetectionConfidence();


    // output relevant info
    $fulfilmentText = $queryResult->getFulfillmentText();


    $sessionsClient->close();
}
echo detect_intent_texts('vehicle-test-cd4f0','text chat','123456','en-US','America/New_York');
// END dialogflow_detect_intent_text
```

**Environment Details**

- OS : Linux
- PHP 7.1
- dialogflow v2

I have modified the script when sending data from detectIntent.
But my queryParams object returns me empty data, therefore the default timezone mentioned in the agent is considered. My main concern is to send TimeZone in the request. Which i am able to do with the online testing in google cloud interface https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent?apix=true. The same implementation is not working for me.  What i am doing wrong? Please suggest.

```
/*
Modified script
All the other statements
*/

// I tried to add this code before the detectintent method to get timezone but the variable returns empty data. 
// get response and relevant info

//queryParams optional adding new code before detectintent
$optionalArgs = new QueryParameters();
$optionalArgs->setTimeZone('America/New_York');
$optionalArgs->getTimeZone();

$optionArgs = (array)$optionalArgs;

$response = $sessionsClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput, $optionArgs);// I have added $optionArgs for adding time zone

// other statements
//
// end of code
```

Comment: Please improve your Code format so others can read it much better. Thank you.